# how do I use getdate() in SSRS while excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: getdate

I am trying to run a report for next day by using `getdate()+1` but I want to exclude weekends and holidays.  To exclude weekends, I included the following in my where statement but it doesn't work.  Ideally it should show Monday's results if I am running on Friday.  But instead I am getting no results.

Below is my query:

```
select * from table 
where CONVERT(DATE, [Appointment_DateTime]) = CONVERT(DATE, getdate()+1)
and DATEPART(w,CONVERT(DATE, [Appointment_DateTime])) NOT IN (1,7)
```

I am using not in (1,7) since sunday is the first day of the server so I am excluding sunday and Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show Monday data on Friday, you should add three days if it's Friday today:

```
select * 
from table 
where CONVERT(DATE, [Appointment_DateTime]) = CONVERT(DATE, getdate() + IIF(DATEPART(w,CONVERT(DATE, [Appointment_DateTime])) = 6, 3, 1))
    and DATEPART(w,CONVERT(DATE, [Appointment_DateTime])) NOT IN (1,7)
```

another approach is to use different conditions for Mon-Thu and Fri:

```
select * 
from table 
where CONVERT(DATE, [Appointment_DateTime]) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() + 1)
    and DATEPART(weekday,CONVERT(DATE, [Appointment_DateTime])) in (2,3,4,5)
union all
select * 
from table 
where CONVERT(DATE, [Appointment_DateTime]) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() + 3)
    and DATEPART(weekday,CONVERT(DATE, [Appointment_DateTime])) = 6
```

first part of union will yield rows for Mon-Thu, second one for Fridays

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I run this report every day so if I add three days on Friday, I would need to fix the query on Monday again to do +1.  Is there an alternate solution?

Comment: read my answer carefully, `IIF(...)` adds 1 day every day except on Fridays, no need to change query then

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  When I run the query you edited, I still don't get any results.

Comment: do you have any appointments for this Monday (try hardcoding the first condition) also try `select @@DATEFIRST` to see if Sunday is really first day of week on your system

Comment: Thanks for your response again.  Yes, I do appointments for Monday.  I ran select @@DATEFIRST and I get 7 as my result.  What needs to be changed in the query? Thanks.

Comment: this definitely should work, try another approach, I edited my answer

Comment: I am sorry but the second approach is still not giving me any results.